# Efficient usage of OneToMany for Spring Data object retrieval

Tags: kotlin, spring-data-jpa

In an application, we have an `Entity` that can logically contain many `EntityComponent`. Lately, we have noticed a performance issue when retrieving an entity that contains many components. Upon inspection in Jaeger, it seems like each component renders a separate `SELECT` statement. My hypothesis is that something in how these objects are defined in code leads to this behaviour, and I'd like to find out whether I can change something so that only query is performed, regardless of the number of children.

From the `Entity` class:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    val components: List<EntityComponent>,
```

Does this look right, or can something be changed?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `@BatchSize`-annotation to your field... A `@BatchSize(size = 20)` for example will allow Hibernate to apply batch fetching of up to 20 `EntityComponent`s with each query...

[BatchSize annotation javadoc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/BatchSize.html)